# Why does Spell Queller prevent spells from resolving?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Why when a spell get "[Spell Queller](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSpell%20Queller%5d)ed" the spell does not resolve, even though it's not written that it "counters" but instead "exiles" the spell? Is there a special ruling or am I missing something? (I'm still kinda new to Magic.) I've been told numerous time that a card effect still resolves (if not countered) even if it's removed from the stack, like for example if I play [Stasis Snare](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bStasis%20Snare%5d) on a creature that has a "enter the battlefield" effect that effect will still resolve unless it is "countered."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Spell Queller](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSpell%20Queller%5d) exiles the spell itself. The other situation you're talking about is removing the *source* of an ability on the stack, while leaving the ability there on the stack.

Spells and abilities can only resolve if they're on the stack. So when Spell Queller exiles a spell, it's just gone. There's nothing there to resolve anymore.

On the other hand, if your opponent casts a creature with an "enters the battlefield" ability, say [Ulrich of the Krallenhorde](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bUlrich%20of%20the%20Krallenhorde%5d), we're talking about two objects: Ulrich himself (a creature on the battlefield), and its ability (on the stack). The two are independent. If you actually removed the *ability*, say by casting [Summary Dismissal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSummary%20Dismissal%5d), then it wouldn't resolve. But if you remove Ulrich, the ability is still there to resolve and give the targeted creature +4/+4.

Same goes for activated abilities, like [Thermo-Alchemist](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bThermo-Alchemist%5d)'s ability to deal one damage to each opponent. If you remove the Thermo-Alchemist, the ability is still there to deal you damage.

Comment: I got you. That make sense i was definitely missing something. Great explanation. I learned something. Thank you.